# 12c Jdeveloper gives Cannot convert 20 of type class oracle.jbo.domain.DBSequence to class java.lang.Long error while inserting new record

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have two tables Customers and Sectors that are connected with foreignkey. Customers table has sector_id as a foreignkey, customer_id as a primary key. Both Customers and Sectors primary keys' are type of DBSequence in Jdeveloper 12c Fusion web application. In Customers table I cretaed ListOfValues of sector_id and in Customers table sector_id is seen as Long type. In 11g version I did not get such an error even though everything is same. When I try createInsert a Customer I get this error :
Cannot convert 20 of type class oracle.jbo.domain.DBSequence to class java.lang.Long.

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of `sector_id` from `DBSequence` to `Long` in entity object

Comment: But when I change it, it does not increase automatically when inserting new sector into sectors table.

Comment: create a new readOnly viewObject as  a ListOfValues  from sectors table and use it ,where sector_id  of type Long